# Error: Could not load module in dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have this super simple code in index.html

```
<script src="../../dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<script>
    dojo.require("dojo.fx");
    dojo.ready(function(){
        dojo.byId("greeting").innerHTML += ", from " + dojo.version;
        dojo.fx.slideTo({
            top: 100,
            left: 200,
            node: dojo.byId("greeting")
        }).play();
    });
</script>
```

I get error
Error: Could not load 'dojo.fx'; last tried './fx.js'

Note: I hadn't changed dojo's directory structure. I'm using dojo 1.6

```
-dojo
-dijit
-dojox
-labs
 -ex01
  -index.html
```

Comment: uhm, which dojo-version do you actually use?

Comment: You could also try to load dojo from other source (say google cloud) <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was dojo simply won't run from my local filesystem.

> Run your source code from a web server, not the file system, even if
>   the web server is    running on your development machine. The
>   browser's handling of HTTP requests from the local file system are
>   more restrictive than from a web server, even when it's running in the
>   same machine. For consistent results, you should always run Dojo from
>   within any HTTP web server (Apache, nginx, Tomcat, IIS, Jetty, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly fine. I have setup a jsFiddle with Dojo 1.6 here: http://jsfiddle.net/6h82P/

Here's a complete example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
     <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.0/dojo/dojo.xd.js.uncompressed.js'>               </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="greeting">Hello</div>
  <script>
      dojo.require("dojo.fx");
      dojo.ready(function(){
      dojo.byId("greeting").innerHTML += ", from " + dojo.version;
      dojo.fx.slideTo({
        top: 100,
        left: 200,
        node: dojo.byId("greeting")
       }).play();
    });
   </script>

  </body>
 </html>
```